# Vue.js проблема с checkbox

Tags: vue.js

Есть форма заказа как отдельный компонент, его 2 раза или больше использую на странице, в нем есть чекбоксы. Если я кликаю по `label` то и в другом экземпляре компонента он также кликается, если кликать по самому инпуту то все норм. Хочу сделать кастомный чекбокс, в котором `input` скрыт и нужно кликать только по `label`, но с ним не получается. Как решить проблему?

```
<template>
<form action="" @submit.prevent="formSubmit" class="order-form">
    <h2>Начать работу</h2>
    <div class="order-content">
        <div class="order-left">
            <div class="order__row">
                <label class="down" :for="'order_name_' + makeHash">Имя</label>
                <input :id="'order_name_' + makeHash" type="text" :name="'order_name_' + makeHash" v-model="orderName" required="required" maxlength="50">
            </div>
            <div class="order__row">
                <label class="down" :for="'order_tel_' + makeHash">Номер телефона</label>
                <input :id="'order_tel_' + makeHash" type="tel" :name="'order_tel_' + makeHash" v-model="orderTel" required="required" maxlength="15">
            </div>
            <div class="order__row">
                <label class="down" :for="'order_email_' + makeHash">Email</label>
                <input :id="'order_email_' + makeHash" type="email" :name="'order_email_' + makeHash" v-model="orderEmail" maxlength="40">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="order-center">

        </div>
        <div class="order-right">
            <div class="order-right-pick">
                Выберите услугу:
            </div>
            <ul class="">
                <li v-for="(feature, index) in features">
                    <input type="checkbox"
                           :value="feature"
                           :id="'cb-feature-'+index"
                           v-model="selection.features">
                    <label :for="'cb-feature-'+index">{{feature}}</label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="order__footer">
        <div class="border-btn-box pointer-large">
            <div class="border-btn-inner">
                <button :submit="true" class="border-btn" data-text="Отправить">Отправить</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

код vue

```
import DOMPurify from 'dompurify';
import MaskedInput from 'vue-masked-input';
import swal from 'sweetalert';
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    name: 'order',
    components: {
        MaskedInput
    },
    data: function(){
        return {
            orderName: '',
            orderEmail: '',
            orderTel: '',
            errs: [],
            token: '',
            chatId: '',

            features: ["Reactivity", "Encapsulation", "Data Binding"],
            selection: {
                features: []
            },
        };
    },
    methods: {
        formSubmit: function(){
            let name = this.orderNameCleaned;
            let tel = this.orderTelCleaned;
            let email = this.orderEmailCleaned;

            if(name.length > 0){
                this.removeError('name');
            } else {
                this.addError('name');
            }


            if(tel.length > 0){
                this.removeError('tel');
            } else {
                this.addError('tel');
            }

            if(this.checkErrors()){
                let msg =   '<b>Новая заявка от ' + name + '!</b>\n';
                msg +=  'Номер телефона: ' + tel + '.\n';
                msg +=  'Email: ' + email + '.\n';
                this.sendMsg(msg);

            } else {
                let msg = "";
                Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.errs, function(err){
                    if(err == 'name'){
                        msg += 'Поле имя не должно быть пустое. ';
                    }
                    if(err == 'tel'){
                        msg += 'Поле телефон не должно быть пустое. ';
                    }
                });
                this.showErrorAlert(msg);
            }
        },
        sanitize: function(s){
            return DOMPurify.sanitize(s).trim().replace(/\s+/g,' ').replace(/_/g, '');
        },
        checkError: function(err){
            return this.errs.indexOf(err);
        },
        addError: function(err){
            if(this.checkError(err) == -1){
                this.errs.push(err);
            }
        },
        removeError: function(err){
            if(this.checkError(err) != -1){
                this.errs.splice(this.checkError(err), 1);
            }
        },
        checkErrors: function(){
            if(this.errs.length == 0){
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        },
        showErrorAlert: function(msg){
            swal("Ошибка", msg, "error");
            console.log(msg);
        },
        showSuccessAlert: function(){
            swal("Успешно!", "Ваша заявка принята и будет рассмотрена в ближайшее время.", "success");
            this.orderName = '';
            this.orderTel = '';
            this.orderEmail = '';
        },
        sendMsg: function(msg){
            let url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + this.token + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + this.chatId + '&text=' + encodeURI(msg) + '&parse_mode=html';
            let $this = this;

            axios.get(url).then((response) => {
                let ok = response.data.ok;
                if(ok){
                    $this.showSuccessAlert();
                } else {
                    $this.showErrorAlert('Случилась какая-то ошибка. Подождите немного и повторите еще раз.');
                }
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
                $this.showErrorAlert('Случилась какая-то ошибка. Подождите немного и повторите еще раз.');
            });
        }
    },
    computed: {
        makeHash: function(){
            let hash = "";
            let possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
            for(let i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                hash += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

            return hash;
        },
        orderNameCleaned: function(){
            return this.sanitize(this.orderName);
        },
        orderTelCleaned: function(){
            return this.sanitize(this.orderTel);
        },
        orderEmailCleaned: function(){
            return this.sanitize(this.orderEmail);
        },
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Накидал простой пример, следуйте ему и проблем не будет.

```js
const FormOrder = {
  name: 'form-order',
  data() {
    return {
      hash_id: null,
      features: ["Reactivity", "Encapsulation", "Data Binding"],
      selection: {
        features: []
      },
    }
  },
  computed: {
    makeHash(name) {
      return (name) => `${name}_${this.hash_id}`
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    // Ваш метод генерации уникалного значения без изменений в логике.
    let i, hash = '',
      possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      hash += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    }

    this.hash_id = hash;
  },
  methods: {
    formSubmit() {}
  },
  template: `<div>
    <form action="" @submit.prevent="formSubmit" class="order-form">
      <label :for="makeHash('order_name')">Имя</label>
      <input :id="makeHash('order_name')" />

      <label :for="makeHash('order_email')">Email</label>
      <input :id="makeHash('order_email')" />

      <ul class="">
        <li v-for="(feature, index) in features">
          <input type="checkbox"
            :id="makeHash('cb-feature-'+index)"
            :value="feature"
            v-model="selection.features" />
          <label :for="makeHash('cb-feature-'+index)">{{feature}}</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </form>
  </div>`
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    'form-order': FormOrder
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <form-order></form-order>
  <form-order></form-order>
  <form-order></form-order>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: @РустамГимранов, а ситуацию не спасает уникальный `id`?

Comment: @РустамГимранов, а так?) Для автора вопроса, прокомментирую код.

Comment: @РустамГимранов, я понял, надо вместо моего кода в `mounted` прописать его метод `makeHash`. Ну а так проблема решена.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96165/discussion-between-doox911-and--).

Comment: спасибо!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Alexander, а приня0ть ответ)?

Comment: принял, все работает, спасибо за помощь