# Как показать данные из массива объектов в списке?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Есть функция, которая получает массив `policies[]`:

```
getPolicies() {
  let self = this;
  HttpService.methods.get('/policies')
    .then(function (response) {
      self.policies = response.data.data
      console.log(self.policies);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    })
}
```

И есть такое чекбокс меню:

```
<div class="dropdown-checkbox form-group">
  <label class="label-title"><p>Select</p></label>
  <ul>
    <li><label><input value="1" type="checkbox">1</label></li>
    <li><label><input value="2" type="checkbox">2</label></li>
    <li><label><input value="3" type="checkbox">3</label></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

функция `getPolicies` отдаёт:

```
policies=[ { foo: 1, bar: 2}, { foo: 3, bar: 4}, { foo: 5, bar: 6} ]
```

Как показать данные из массива `policies[]` в меню для каждого элемента?

Comment: 1. Скорее всего, тут не нужен `self` используйте стрелочную функцию. 2. Если он вам прям так необходим, то правильно — `const self = this;`. 3. А в чём проблема?

Comment: @Дмытрык страницу делаю на vue, поэтому участники форума могут использовать vue(какие-то методы, директивы) для решения задачи

Comment: @doox911 3. функция getPolicies отдаёт policies=[ { foo: 1, bar: 2}, { foo: 3, bar: 4}, { foo: 5, bar: 6} ]; Хочу сделать меню с чекбоксами, где будет показываться только foo.

Comment: Общий вид данных в `policies[]` надо указать **в вопросе**, вместе с желаемым результатом.

Comment: нужно использовать директиву `v-for`. Знание этой директивы относиться к базовым.  https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-for.

Comment: @Дмытрык использование данной директивы не является решением. У меня этих меню на сайте будет много, а тут когда я выбираю 1 и 2 галочку - они выбираются везде(во всех менюшках)

Comment: @AlinaHomyakova, Это директива Vue, она выполняет только единственную свою функцию, обход структуры - и никак не освобождает от написания логики приложения (в частности, логики поведения "чтобы не выбиралось везде во всех менюшках", которая уже за пределами сути данного вопроса... в том виде, как вопрос изложен сейчас).

Comment: Компонент создайте, на примере этого ответа https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1002575/256824

Answer (score 0):

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    policies: [
      {
        foo: 1,
        bar: 2,
        checked: false,
      },
      {
        foo: 3,
        bar: 2,
        checked: true,
      },
      {
        foo: 5,
        bar: 2,
        checked: false,
      },
    ],
  },
  methods: {
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <template>
    <div class="dropdown-checkbox form-group">
      <label class="label-title"><p>Select</p></label>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="polici, key in policies">
          <label>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              v-model="polici.checked"
              :value="polici.checked"
            >
            {{polici.foo}}
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```